# SQL: trying to get unrecorded dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, subquery

I am having a table that contains (date and subscribers) on that day, some days there will be NEW subscribers to my service. and I wrote a query that gets me the number (count) of NEW subscribers for each day. BUT some days, there's no new subscribers, these days don't show at all (no new subscribers = no record). I want them to show, and I want the records with no new subscribers to show with 0 new subscribers.

e.g. The subscribers table:

```
Date        Subscribers
03-08-2018   a,b
04-08-2018   a,b,c
05-08-2018   a,c,d
06-08-2018   a,
07-08-2018   a,e,g,k,l
```

the table I get:

```
Date          New_Subs
03-08-2018      2
04-08-2018      1
05-08-2018      1
07-08-2018      4
```

And I should be getting:

```
Date          New_Subs
03-08-2018      2
04-08-2018      1
05-08-2018      1
06-08-2018      0
07-08-2018      4
```

P.S I get the new subs using the function min(date) to get the first date it shows up in the database

```
SELECT count(*) Subscribers , convert(varchar, creatingdate, 23)
FROM Payments p
JOIN
(SELECT msisdn , Min(creatingdate) AS day
FROM Payments p
GROUP BY MSISDN) groupedtt 
ON p.MSISDN = groupedtt.MSISDN 
AND p.CreatingDate = groupedtt.day
group by convert(varchar, creatingdate, 23)
order by convert(varchar, creatingdate, 23)
```

Comment: This seems like a calendar sort of thing. Where you have a date table with all the dates and you join your data onto that so that there are all dates returned that you want even if you don't have any data for a certain date.

Comment: This is a frequently asked question. I wish I could find a good sample question on SO. As already mentioned you first need a _calendar_ table (google it) then you need to outer join to it. Here's an example: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75473/insert-missing-dates-from-a-query

Answer (score 0):

You could use `master..spt_values`. Querying it with `Type = 'P'` gives you the numbers from 0 to 2047. Use `DATEADD(DAY, -1 * master..sp_values.number, GETDATE())` gives you the last 2048 dates. You can start your select with this table and use a left join with subscribers table to get all subscribers. After that, COUNT will return also 0 for those days that have nothing.